# Polymer: custom element submits form on Enter

Tags: javascript, polymer, custom-element

I have created a custom form element for Polymer `iron-form`, based on `paper-input`. The problem is that normally `paper-input` in a form ignores press Enter event and does not submit the form, but my element does. Is there any way to ban press Enter event for this element?

Comment: Can you provide some code that demonstrates what you're doing?

Comment: Actually I just found out that iron-form automatically submits on Enter if it has only one form element.

Comment: You can answer your own question - then accept it after some cool-down phase - to make it obvious to others the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I think using iron-a11y-keys and then giving your custom function on enter should help. Try and keep the same function name as in iron-form so that it gets overwritten